# With Dynamic Feature module not able to build the project

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx, dynamic-delivery

I migrated my project to **androidX**. After which I was trying to add one dynamic feature module. But after adding it, I am not able to build the project.
I am getting an error similar to:

`Expected configuration ':feature:debugCompileClasspath' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.`

I am not able to rectify how this can be resolved. Did anyone came up with this kind of error? Please suggest some solution or workaround.

Tried changing/adding flavors in feature module's `build.gradle` file, but no luck.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':feature:processDebugManifest'.
> Expected configuration ':feature:debugCompileClasspath' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':attendance:processDebugManifest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
27 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 24 up-to-date
```

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this? I am kind of fighting with this.

Comment: @iZBasit The issue was with my dependencies in build.gradle file. Some of the third party dependencies were not supporting androidX, so when I commented that dependnecy, it successfully built the project and allowed me to create dynamic feature module as well.

Comment: Wow. If thats the case then I am going to lose all my hair. I have a LOT of dependencies. If you don't mind can you share which dependencies you had to remove?

Comment: That was not a common dependency. You can check what all third party dependencies you are using and just think of which is not supporting androidX. You can also check their release notes.

Comment: Man, I removed all my `android.support` dependencies. Still not building. Anything else you might have done to get it to work?